# eslint: Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lint

I have a component in react and I am getting an error lint:

**Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>`  arrow-body-style**

```
export function dashConfig(config) {
  return (Component) => {
    return (props) => {
      const { data, isLoaded, error } = useDashConfig({ ...config });

      return <Component {...props} remoteConfig={{ data, isLoaded, error }} />;
    };
  };
}
```

Which return should I remove? I didn't quite understand the explanation. Thanks!

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing an arrow function body that just immediately returns:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("hello");
  return () => {
    return () => {
      console.log("world");
    }
  }
}

// Is the same as below

function bar() {
  console.log("hello");
  return () => () => {
    console.log("world");
  }
};

foo()()();
bar()()();
```

This applies to your own code in the following:

```
export function dashConfig(config) {
  return (Component) => {
    return (props) => {
      const { data, isLoaded, error } = useDashConfig({ ...config });

      return <Component {...props} remoteConfig={{ data, isLoaded, error }} />;
    };
  };
}

// Is the same as this

export function dashConfig(config) {
  return (Component) => (props) => {
    const { data, isLoaded, error } = useDashConfig({ ...config });

    return <Component {...props} remoteConfig={{ data, isLoaded, error }} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export function dashConfig(config) =>
  Component =>
    props => {
      const { data, isLoaded, error } = useDashConfig({ ...config });

      return <Component {...props} remoteConfig={{ data, isLoaded, error }} />;
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is only one `return` in the statement, we should remove the `return` like the following example.

```
res => {
    return new Promise().resolve(null);
}
```

Should be in this way

```
res => (new Promise().resolve(null));
```

To your case, it should be like the following

```
export function dashConfig(config) =>
  Component =>
    props => {
      const { data, isLoaded, error } = useDashConfig({ ...config });
      return <Component {...props} remoteConfig={{ data, isLoaded, error }} />;
    };
  };
}
```